# Error while installing 'n'

Tags: node.js, npm

Trying to install 'n' but getting following error:

```
npm isntall  -g n
/usr/lib
└── n@2.1.0 

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-57-generic
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "isntall" "-g" "n"
npm ERR! node v0.10.25
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.3
npm ERR! path /usr/lib/node_modules/.staging
npm ERR! code ELOOP
npm ERR! errno 51

npm ERR! ELOOP, unlink '/usr/lib/node_modules/.staging'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/www/yeoman-start/npm-debug.log
```

What' s the issue and how can I handle this ?

Comment: you have a typo in `isntall`! Try `npm install -g n`.

Comment: @Beat npm handles this misspelling.  The issue is that the OP is getting into a dependency loop `code ELOOP`.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's start with this:

```
 ELOOP: {
   errno: 51,
   message: 'too many symbolic links encountered'
 }
```

Second,
I'm not sure if you have to install `n` via `npm` but if you don't, there're three more alternatives:

1. Using `make install`:

   To do that, simply clone the repository (`git clone https://github.com/tj/n.git`), cd into the directory (`cd n`), and run the command.
2. Using `n-install`:

   Just run `curl -L http://git.io/n-install | bash` command and that'll do whatever you need.
3. Using `brew`:

   This is what I'd choose though. Install `brew` (or let's say [linuxbrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew)) first, and then run `brew install n`. That's it.